# My exception is not caught when compiling with Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, exception, qt-creator

I have written a simple consolebased webserver that I am trying to port to Qt so I can develop a GUI for it.
In my class that controls the reading of files from harddisk I have been using exceptions to indicate when there has been an error reading the file etc.

Now when I try to run the code compiled with Qt 5.7 my catch-block doesn't pick up my exception all of a sudden. Instead it throws it all the way back and crashes.
But when I write catch(...) to pick up all kind of exceptions it works without crashing..

This is the code in my filereading function:

```
   fstream file;
   file.exceptions( ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit );

    try{
        string content;
        //Open file and read the file to string
        file.open(this->getDirectory() + filename, ios_base::in|ios_base::binary);
        file.seekg(0, file.beg);
        char tmpChar = 0;
        while( file.peek() != EOF )
        {
            file.read(&tmpChar, sizeof(tmpChar));
            content.push_back(tmpChar);
        }
        file.close();

        unique_ptr<fileObject> tmpPtr( new fileObject(filename, content, "text/html") );

        if( this->addFileToCache(move(tmpPtr) ))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
    catch(const ios_base::failure& e){
        if(file.is_open()) file.close();
        return false;
    }
```

Why isn't this working with Qt? catch(...) picks up the ios_base::failure exception so I don't understand why my code doesn't work anymore..

UPDATE:

When I pick up the exception with a catch(exception &e) and print its info I get the following result:  .what() returns "basic_ios::clear" and typeid(e).name() returns "NSt8ios_base7failureE".

I am compiling with MinGw 5.3.0 32-bit in QtCreator and the compiler I used when my exceptions worked was MinGw-w64 4.7.3.

Comment: Please show a complete code example

Comment: @nos There you have a complete code example

Comment: How do you know that `catch(...)` catches precisely the `ios_base::failure` exception and not any other exception?

Comment: When I print the string typeid(e).name() I get: NSt8ios_base7failureE
And e.what(): basic_ios::clear
It happens exactly when I am excepting a ios_base::failure exception to be thrown.. 
I havent got my head around the Qt library yet with signals and slots etc. Could Qt pick up my exception a rethrow it or something like that?

Comment: There's no such thing as "compiling with Qt Creator." Qt Creator is an IDE, not a compiler.

Comment: Although when I try to cast it dynamically to a ios_base::failure a bad_cast exception is thrown so it doesnt seem to be the same type anyway..

Comment: Qt tries to prevent exceptions from crossing potentially unsafe boundaries. If you can catch(QException &exception) then Qt has caught it, and then rethrown a safer exception

Comment: @RobbieE Thanks for your reply. I just tried it out but it didn´t catch a QException neither..

Comment: @hallos, have you tried to catch `std::exception` and print the stuff its `what()` method returns? `ios_base::failure` exception must inherit from `std::exception` either directly (until C++11) or through some other base classes (since C++11).

Comment: @Dmitry, Yes I have and .what() returns " basic_ios::clear" and typeid(e).name() returns "NSt8ios_base7failureE". This seems to me to actually be a ios_base::failure exception.. Im confused :)

Comment: @hallos, it seems the failure to catch this exception might be due to binary incompatibility between C++11 and C++98 code. What it the target platform you're building on, which exact compiler do you use - name and version? You might be interested to look [here](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/issues/747) and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66145) for more details.

Comment: @Dmitry, My target platform is x86, windows OS. QtCreator is using the MinGw 5.3.0 32-bit compiler, so thats the one Im trying to compile with now. The compiler I used when my exceptions worked was MinGw-w64 4.7.3.
I read through the links briefly and this seems definitely to be my problem! Thanks very much!! You could post an answer if you want to so I can mark it as the answer.  cheers

Comment: @hallos, posted the answer, glad it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66145) of libstdc++ shipped with gcc >= 5.0: some parts of the standard library throw the exceptions using C++98 ABI while the catching code uses C++11 ABI. The bug is still not fixed and it seems there is no simple workaround other than downgrading the compiler and the standard library or not using the exceptions together with iostreams.